# Cannot auth to SVN using IntelliJ

Tags: svn, authentication, intellij-idea, certificate

After a reinstallation of `Windows XP` I have a huge problem with `IntelliJ` and `Subversion` plugin.
I've added an existing project to `IntelliJ`, which was checkouted from `SVN` that needs autorisation (`ssh+svn://`).
During update/commit it asks me for credential. I set username and private key/passphrase but `IntelliJ` rejects it and ask for it again and again.
When I update/commit that project using `TortoiseSVN` with auth cert in `Pageant` loaded (putty tool), it works fine.
Same thing with other projects even checkouted after reinstallation.

How can I fix that issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using a key in the OpenSSH format and entering the key password correctly. I've verified it with my own svn+ssh repository and it works fine.

Comment: After reexport key in `OpenSSH` format it works again. I thought, that my `OpenSSH` version of key was fine, byt probably not. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 9):

In case this helps anyone else: ensure that the `username` field is the same as the one used for SVN and NOT the one registered with IntelliJ.

Comment: This seems to have fixed my problem. Stackoverflow advised me to not say 'thanks' or '+1' in the comment. I don't like being told how to talk to people who have helped me, so thank you and +1.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Intellij are you referring to? The one i use is 9.0.4 and I can't log into svn despite providing the right credentials. The workaround to the problem is to use the svn plugin bundled with Intellij 9.0.2. Just go to the plugins folder of the older installation, copy over the files from the folder svn4idea into the same folder of the 9.0.4 installtion.